# Redirection issue for URL directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to add something to either my htaccess file or within the httpd.conf file on my server (preferred), but I'm not sure how how to do it.

Basically, I need this:

```
https://example.com/example/anything.html
```

to redirect to this:

```
https://example.com/anything.html
```

And not just for this this URL. I need directory `example` stripped out of every URL that has it after `example.com/`

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply need to redirect, assuming that `https://example.com/anything.html` is a valid resource and won't return a 404 if you go there directly, then you can simply do one of the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example/(.*)$ /$1
```

or

```
Redirect 301 /example/ /
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any advantage/disadvantage to using one of these techniques versus another? Assume I'm going to update in my httpd.conf file on the server.

Comment: @jonmrich it depends on what you already have in your htaccess. Performance wise, there's probably no difference. The `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` work exactly the same. You'll want to use mod_rewrite if you already have `RewriteRule` directives in your htaccess (as it's better not to mix the two). Overall, if none of that matters, you want to be able to look at your directives later on and easily tell what's going on, so whatever is most readable to you.